# Exception Value: [Errno 111] Connection refused with djoser and django

Tags: python, django, celery, djoser

I am trying to connect Django and celery .ith Djoser with JWT authentication.
I am not sure how to diagnose this error or where to even start looking.
This error message is so vague and does not point me to the problem.

My Django is as follows

- Request URL: http://localhost/api/v1/auth/users/
- Django Version: 3.2.13
- Python Version: 3.9.5
- djoser==2.1.0
- django-redis==5.2.0
- redis==4.2.2
- celery==5.2.6

My url call is as follows

```
path("api/v1/auth/", include("djoser.urls")),
path("api/v1/auth/", include("djoser.urls.jwt")),
```

Here is the error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/kombu/utils/functional.py", line 30, in __call__
    return self.__value__

During handling of the above exception ('ChannelPromise' object has no attribute '__value__'), another exception occurred:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/kombu/connection.py", line 446, in _reraise_as_library_errors
    yield
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/kombu/connection.py", line 433, in _ensure_connection
    return retry_over_time(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/kombu/utils/functional.py", line 312, in retry_over_time
    return fun(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/kombu/connection.py", line 877, in _connection_factory
    self._connection = self._establish_connection()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/kombu/connection.py", line 812, in _establish_connection
    conn = self.transport.establish_connection()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/kombu/transport/pyamqp.py", line 201, in establish_connection
    conn.connect()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/amqp/connection.py", line 323, in connect
    self.transport.connect()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/amqp/transport.py", line 129, in connect
    self._connect(self.host, self.port, self.connect_timeout)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/amqp/transport.py", line 184, in _connect
    self.sock.connect(sa)

The above exception ([Errno 111] Connection refused) was the direct cause of the following exception:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 181, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/contextlib.py", line 79, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwds)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py", line 54, in wrapped_view
    return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/rest_framework/viewsets.py", line 125, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 509, in dispatch
    response = self.handle_exception(exc)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 469, in handle_exception
    self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 480, in raise_uncaught_exception
    raise exc
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 506, in dispatch
    response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/rest_framework/mixins.py", line 19, in create
    self.perform_create(serializer)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/djoser/views.py", line 144, in perform_create
    settings.EMAIL.activation(self.request, context).send(to)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/templated_mail/mail.py", line 78, in send
    super(BaseEmailMessage, self).send(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/mail/message.py", line 284, in send
    return self.get_connection(fail_silently).send_messages([self])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/djcelery_email/backends.py", line 17, in send_messages
    result_tasks.append(send_emails.delay(chunk_messages, self.init_kwargs))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/celery/app/task.py", line 425, in delay
    return self.apply_async(args, kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/celery/app/task.py", line 575, in apply_async
    return app.send_task(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/celery/app/base.py", line 788, in send_task
    amqp.send_task_message(P, name, message, **options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/celery/app/amqp.py", line 510, in send_task_message
    ret = producer.publish(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/kombu/messaging.py", line 177, in publish
    return _publish(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/kombu/connection.py", line 523, in _ensured
    return fun(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/kombu/messaging.py", line 186, in _publish
    channel = self.channel
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/kombu/messaging.py", line 209, in _get_channel
    channel = self._channel = channel()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/kombu/utils/functional.py", line 32, in __call__
    value = self.__value__ = self.__contract__()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/kombu/messaging.py", line 225, in <lambda>
    channel = ChannelPromise(lambda: connection.default_channel)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/kombu/connection.py", line 895, in default_channel
    self._ensure_connection(**conn_opts)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/kombu/connection.py", line 433, in _ensure_connection
    return retry_over_time(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/contextlib.py", line 135, in __exit__
    self.gen.throw(type, value, traceback)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/kombu/connection.py", line 450, in _reraise_as_library_errors
    raise ConnectionError(str(exc)) from exc

Exception Type: OperationalError at /api/v1/auth/users/
Exception Value: [Errno 111] Connection refused
```

Comment: Took me several hours,

Had to change

`app = Celery("config")`

to

`app = Celery("config", broker="redis://redis:6379/0")`

Comment: I have this same error, is it tied to the celery version?